# radio button with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i have a radio button that shows some text box with javascript.
my code has onclick function so at first it shows all of text boxes.
i tried checked function to select fist option so it only shows first text box on loading ( without click ) but no luck.
i don't know how can i make first option checked and only shows first text box!

```
<div class="radioBtns">
      <label for='rbtnLoginTypeMobile'>
           <input checked type="radio" id="rbtnLoginTypeMobile" name="rbtnLoginType" value='1' onclick="showLogin(1)"/>
           <span>Mobile</span>
      </label>
      <label for='rbtnLoginTypeEmail'>
           <input type="radio" id="rbtnLoginTypeEmail" name="rbtnLoginType" value='0' onclick="showLogin(0)" />
           <span>Email</span>
      </label>
</div>

<div class="mobilelogin">
      <div class="form-group">
           <input type="number" id="mobilelogin" class="form-control form-control-user" name="mobilelogin" placeholder="<?php _e('Mobile') ?>">
       </div>
</div>

<div class="emaillogin">
       <div class="form-group">
           <input type="Email" id="ُemaillogin" class="form-control form-control-user" name="emaillogin" placeholder="<?php _e('Email') ?>">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
           <input type="number" id="ُemaillogin-ver-code" class="form-control form-control-user" name="emaillogin-ver-code" placeholder="<?php _e('Email Verification Code') ?>">
       </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
       function showLogin(val){
          if(val==1)
          {
            $('.emaillogin').css('display','none');
            $('.mobilelogin').css('display','');
          }
          else
          {
            $('.mobilelogin').css('display','none');
            $('.emaillogin').css('display','');
          }
       }
</script>
```

Comment: can't you just simply add `showLogin(1)` after function declaration?

Comment: FYI, I removed the PHP tag. For future reference, only add tags that are relevant to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the same function showLogin on window onload. This one of the ways you can handle this. Another approach could be to call your method showLogin() with argument in the same script block..See the examples below.

Approach 1:

```
window.onload = function(){
      showLogin(1)
    }
```

Approach 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showLogin(val) {

      if (val == 1) {
        $('.emaillogin').css('display', 'none');
        $('.mobilelogin').css('display', '');
      } else {
        $('.mobilelogin').css('display', 'none');
        $('.emaillogin').css('display', '');
      }

    }
    showLogin(1)
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

When your page load just `hide` your email input-box .i.e :

```js
//to hide email textbox on load
$('.emaillogin').css('display', 'none');

function showLogin(val) {
  if (val == 1) {
    $('.emaillogin').css('display', 'none');
    $('.mobilelogin').css('display', '');
  } else {
    $('.mobilelogin').css('display', 'none');
    $('.emaillogin').css('display', '');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radioBtns">
  <label for='rbtnLoginTypeMobile'><input checked type="radio" id="rbtnLoginTypeMobile" name="rbtnLoginType" value='1' onclick="showLogin(1)"/><span>Mobile</span></label>
  <label for='rbtnLoginTypeEmail'><input type="radio" id="rbtnLoginTypeEmail" name="rbtnLoginType" value='0' onclick="showLogin(0)" /><span>Email</span></label>
</div>

<div class="mobilelogin">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" id="mobilelogin" class="form-control form-control-user" name="mobilelogin" placeholder="<?php _e('Mobile') ?>">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="emaillogin">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="Email" id="ُemaillogin" class="form-control form-control-user" name="emaillogin" placeholder="<?php _e('Email') ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" id="ُemaillogin-ver-code" class="form-control form-control-user" name="emaillogin-ver-code" placeholder="<?php _e('Email Verification Code') ?>">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will produce incorrect result if default checked is changed from mobile input to email input.

Comment: @random yes you are right but the op wants first option to check and show only first text-box .

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of `checked input` and then call `showLogin` with value as argument.

```js
function showLogin(val) {
  if (val == 1) {
    $('.emaillogin').css('display', 'none');
    $('.mobilelogin').css('display', '');
  } else {
    $('.mobilelogin').css('display', 'none');
    $('.emaillogin').css('display', '');
  }
}

const val = document.querySelector('input:checked').value;
if (val) {
  showLogin(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radioBtns">
  <label for='rbtnLoginTypeMobile'><input checked type="radio" id="rbtnLoginTypeMobile" name="rbtnLoginType"
                value='1' onclick="showLogin(1)" /><span>Mobile</span></label>
  <label for='rbtnLoginTypeEmail'><input type="radio" id="rbtnLoginTypeEmail" name="rbtnLoginType" value='0'
                onclick="showLogin(0)" /><span>Email</span></label>
</div>

<div class="mobilelogin">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" id="mobilelogin" class="form-control form-control-user" name="mobilelogin" placeholder="<?php _e('Mobile') ?>">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="emaillogin">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="Email" id="ُemaillogin" class="form-control form-control-user" name="emaillogin" placeholder="<?php _e('Email') ?>">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" id="ُemaillogin-ver-code" class="form-control form-control-user" name="emaillogin-ver-code" placeholder="<?php _e('Email Verification Code') ?>">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Swati, answer is useful,
also you can only set the val of mobile login type to 1 and set your css on document ready like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(()=>{
        $('#rbtnLoginTypeMobile').val(1)
        $('.emaillogin').css('display','none');
      $('.mobilelogin').css('display','');
    })
    function showLogin(val)
    {
    if(val==1)
    {
      $('.emaillogin').css('display','none');
      $('.mobilelogin').css('display','');
    }
    else
    {
      $('.mobilelogin').css('display','none');
      $('.emaillogin').css('display','');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the "display: none;" in your div.

```html
<div class="emaillogin" style="display: none;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="Email" id="ُemaillogin" class="form-control form-control-user" name="emaillogin" placeholder="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" id="ُemaillogin-ver-code" class="form-control form-control-user" name="emaillogin-ver-code" placeholder="email">
    </div>
</div>
```